# Spinner taking whole space below it in android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to make a xml activity as shown below in image in graphical layout.

Like in graphical layout shown on left

[image]

The spinner i made is taking whole space till the bottom of the activity due to which the button made disappears.

XML File:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/select_project_chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="Select Project To Rename"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_for_rename"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/select_project_chart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:prompt="@string/select_a_project"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/new_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/select_project_chart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/select_project_chart"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="New Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextsumeet" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/rename_pro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner_for_rename"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_for_rename"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:text="Rename"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

If i try to move button or the spinner it gives class cast exception error saying button cant be cast to spinner.

How to solve this ?

Comment: share the graphical layout if you could

Comment: sorry but i didnt get you !  the picture on left is the screenshot of my graphical layout from eclipse ! and on right its the actual screenshot from phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code tells that you had given `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` wrap_content will occupy space based on the drop down list item layout size...

So, for your drop down list item give specific height interms of "dp" like `android:layout_height="65dp"` and `android:margin="3dp"`. It will solve your problem....

This solution for one screen size only. If you want to adjust the height and margin according to display, you have to implement multiple screen support for your app.

Use this for spinner Drop down item layout :

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl_person_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:margin="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TextView" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried that before and the app force closes !  and no of items in spinner are less so i think it should take less space then but it it takes all the space below

Comment: after moving widgets here and there .... then i tried changing android:layout_height="45dp" as you said ... that worked..!! first it use to force close ! anyways now solved Thanx

Answer (score 1):

As per your layout you have the control one below the order.. Use should use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and this will fix ur problem also.

Answer (score 0):

For class cast exception, just clean the project before running.